# Bundler: install local gem with system gems

Tags: ruby, bundler

I am using rvm, ruby 2.0.0 and bundler.

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'logger'
gem 'mygem', :path => '.'
```

`bundle` installs both of them gems. `bundle show` shows `logger` is installed in `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems`, but `mygem` is installed in the path where the gem is located.

Is there any way to get `bundle` to install the local gem into rvm's `gems` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Bundler treats path gems differently and does not install them to your `GEM_PATH`. This is so that you don't need to reinstall as you make changes.

It is not normal or necessary for a gem to point to itself or its runtime dependencies in its `Gemfile`. You might want to add `gemspec` to do this automatically. See http://bundler.io/v1.3/rubygems.html